# Correctly using the numpy's convolve with an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, conv-neural-network, convolution

I was watching [Andrew Ng's videos on CNN](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/lecture/o7CWi/padding) and wanted to to convolve a `6 x 6` image with a `3 x 3` filter. The way I approached this with numpy is as follows:

```
image = np.ones((6,6))
filter = np.ones((3,3))

convolved = np.convolve(image, filter)
```

Running this gives an error saying:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I could comprehend from the [numpy documentation of convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) on how to correctly use the `convolve` method.

Also, is there a way I could do a strided convolutions with numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.convolve` function, unfortunately, only works for *1-D* convolution. That's why you get an error; you need a function that allows you to perform 2-D convolution.

*However*, even if it did work, you actually have the wrong operation. What is called *convolution* in machine learning is more properly termed *cross-correlation* in mathematics. They're actually almost the same; convolution involves flipping the filter matrix followed by performing cross-correlation.

To solve your problem, you can look at `scipy.signal.correlate` (also, don't use `filter` as a name, as you'll shadow the inbuilt function):

```
from scipy.signal import correlate

image = np.ones((6, 6))
f = np.ones((3, 3))

correlate(image, f)
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 2., 1.],
       [2., 4., 6., 6., 6., 6., 4., 2.],
       [3., 6., 9., 9., 9., 9., 6., 3.],
       [3., 6., 9., 9., 9., 9., 6., 3.],
       [3., 6., 9., 9., 9., 9., 6., 3.],
       [3., 6., 9., 9., 9., 9., 6., 3.],
       [2., 4., 6., 6., 6., 6., 4., 2.],
       [1., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 2., 1.]])
```

This is the standard setting of full cross-correlation. If you want to remove elements which would [rely on the zero-padding](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html#scipy.signal.correlate), pass `mode='valid'`:

```
from scipy.signal import correlate

image = np.ones((6, 6))
f = np.ones((3, 3))

correlate(image, f, mode='valid')
```

Output:

```
array([[9., 9., 9., 9.],
       [9., 9., 9., 9.],
       [9., 9., 9., 9.],
       [9., 9., 9., 9.]])
```

Comment: I see that that the output is an `8x8` matrix. From what I followed through the videos, it had to be a `4x4` matrix.

Comment: @SuhailGupta the `8x8` array is produced by full cross-correlation, which is the default. If you're performing cross-correlation in a machine learning context, you probably want the cross-correlation only on the unpadded elements, which you can get with `mode='valid'`. I have edited my answer to reflect this.